# get shipping description by ko

Tags: magento2, knockoutjs

this code return shipping method title ...
how i can get shipping description ?

```
define(
[
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote'
],
function ($, Component, quote) {
    return Component.extend({
        defaults: {
            template: 'Magento_Checkout/summary/shipping'
        },
        quoteIsVirtual: quote.isVirtual(),
        totals: quote.getTotals(),
        getShippingMethodTitle: function() {

            if (!this.isCalculated()) {

                return '';
            }
            var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();
            return shippingMethod ? shippingMethod.carrier_title + " - " + shippingMethod.method_title : '';
        },
        isCalculated: function() {
            return this.totals() && this.isFullMode() && null != quote.shippingMethod();
        },
        getValue: function() {
            if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                return this.notCalculatedMessage;
            }
            var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount;
            return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Have you added custom field "Description" in shipping method?

Comment: Seem that the shipping methods don't have a description by default.

Comment: @PareshaU the quote does not have description by defaulte !?!

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh how i can add shipping description !!?

Comment: @ghdarvishani by default quote does not support description field.You have to add your custom field.

Comment: @PareshaU ok but how ? i am new in magento 2 ...can you help me 
?

Comment: In which shipping method you want to add description field?

Comment: @PareshaU it's custom shipping method ...is it important?

Comment: If you have created your custom shipping method then you have created system.xml in etc/adminhtml. In that file you can create add field.

Comment: @PareshaU    getShippingDescription: function() {
                return quote.shippingDescription();
             },
but return error : Uncaught TypeError: Unable to process binding "text: function (){return getShippingDescription() }"

Answer (score 0):

Try this see it works for you

```
quote.shippingMethod()['carrier_code'] + '_' + quote.shippingMethod()['method_code']
```